# How to use IUserStore to find user based on custom column

Tags: identityserver4, .net-6.0

I have a class I'm using to get user info from the DB:

```
public class MyBedrockUserStore : IUserStore<MyUser>
{
    async Task<BedrockUser> IUserStore<BedrockUser>.FindByIdAsync(string userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {...}
}
```

I'm using DI:

```
.AddScoped<IUserStore<MyUser>, MyUserStore>();
```

I'd like to create a similar method called `FindByIdentityProviderIdAsync()` in order to find a user based on a different column.

Is this impossible because I'm limited to what is available in `IUserStore`, if not, how do you go about doing it?